# React Native problem: WebView has been removed from React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, mobile, react-native-webview

I built new React Native project yesterday using react-native-cli.
But when running the project with my android phone, I got this error in red screen.

> Invariant Violation: WebView has been removed from React Native. It can now be installed and imported from 'react-native-webview' instead of 'react-native'. See 'https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview'.

I never used WebView and here is my "package.json".

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-image-slider": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.13.6",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.3.3",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.7.6",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "install-peers": "^1.0.3",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.57.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I tried to fix this problem for a whole day but I couldn't.
I just think 'react-native-gesture-handler' causes this problem.
Anyone who has much experience of React-Native, please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: However, used yarn instead of npm. Removed node_modules folder and ran "yarn install" command, then it's okay. I'm not sure about the reason. Thank you for help, everyone.

Answer (score 5):

Run this command in your root folder:
npm i **react-native-webview**

---

Please see this npm package first

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview

---

Run the project again in your android and IOS device with this command: **react-native run-android or react-native run-ios**

---

Import the package:

```js
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview'
```

---

Use webview as:

```
<WebView source={{ uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/' }} />
```

Comment: OP mentioned he's not importing WebView in his code

Comment: In case if you are working with "expo" tool, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169746/crypto-getrandomvalues-not-supported

Answer (score 1):

Basically your guess is correct, it's affected by `react-native-gesture-handler`.

#### Reason

This is the file that depends on webview.
https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/blob/1.0.10/GestureHandler.js

#### Solution

1. upgrade the `react-native-gesture-handler` to latest version which has already replaced webview from react-native to react-native-webview
2. run `yarn install` and rebuild your project

Comment: after update react-native-gesture-handler i got this error Execution failed for task ':react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

Answer (score 0):

Try to

1. delete all your build-files in android folder and ios folder
2. delete your node_modules
3. npm install
4. Try to run it again

Comment: Hi, Thank  you for your reply.
But build-files means which files?

And npm install again after delete node_modules folder?

Comment: Delete the files and folders in /Users/xxx/projectname/android/build and /Users/xxx/projectname/ios/build... Delete node_modules folder and run npm install again...

Comment: There is no build folders in android and ios folders.

Comment: Oh, it's "projectname/android/app/build" folder.

Comment: Yup if it's not there means you haven't build/run the app

Comment: I did as you said. But I get new error and build folder and files aren't generated again.

Comment: Have you ever experienced this problem? Your method doesn't fix the problem. It's same.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's clearly mentioned there in the warning:

> WebView has been **removed from React Native**. It can now be installed and imported from '**react-native-webview**' instead of 'react-native'

I suppose you are now using the following some where in your code

```
import {
  WebView,
} from 'react-native';
```

Now onwards you shall do the following instead
`import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';`

To get started with react-native-webivew, you can follow the [getting started document here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started.md)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I told already I never used WebView.

Comment: Yes, but you might accidentally imported or copied from some other source. Maybe you can perform a keyword searching on your project? Just to double confirm.

Comment: No, I can't find word "WebView" in search. Is this enough?