# crypto.getRandomValues() not supported

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-webview

I'm getting this error with npm `react-native-webview@9.0.1` when I try to generate a QR code with `react-native-qrcode-generator`

I'm using react-native with an expo managed workflow. And the thing is it works on iOS, and i only get the error on Android

I searched for a solution myself and I tried installing `react-native-get-random-values` but that also didn't work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Which Expo SDK are you using? Which version of `react-native-qrcode-generator`?

Comment: expo@~37.0.3 and react-native-qrcode-generator@1.2.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just had the same issue on android. Works fine on iOS.

I solved it with:

1. Uninstall the existing one `npm uninstall react-native-webview`
2. Use `expo install react-native-webview` instead.

Comment: In my case only `expo install react-native-webview` was enough, no need to uninstall npm package.

Comment: Need to run pod install in ios directory

Answer (score 30):

Install react-native-get-random-values
Import it before uuid:

```
import 'react-native-get-random-values';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
```

Answer (score 6):

1. Install react-native-get-random-values using this command-

   ```
   npm install react-native-get-random-values
   ```
2. Import react-native-get-random-values before uuid like this-

   ```
   import "react-native-get-random-values";
   import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
   ```

It worked for me. I hope it will work for you as well.

Comment: how to get random numbers between 1 to 10 using this library?

Answer (score 5):

Here is what worked for me

1. Install react-native-get-random-values

   ```
   npm install --save react-native-get-random-values
   ```
2. Import react-native-get-random-values before webview import (**VERY IMPORTANT**)

   ```
   import 'react-native-get-random-values';
   import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';
   ```

For more information, please read this [issue](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/1312).

Answer (score 1):

I made a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@superkalo/so---qr-code-generator) with Expo SDK 37 and the exact versions you mention:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react-native-webview": "9.0.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-generator": "1.2.1"
  }
}
```

It works just fine on my Android phone. The issue must be somewhere else in your implementation.

If you've changed versions recently, try to delete your `node_modules` and install packages again. Double-check my example and let me know if you do something different?

Comment: Thanks, i checked the snack and it worked and then updated to react-native-webview@9.0.1 and it also worked so it must have been some other dependancy 

**So the moral here is that it wasn't an issue with react-native-webview**

Comment: @jsnid00 I replied quicker. I double-checked with you the versions of the libraries. I created a snack to double-check and proof that it works. My answer was correct. I spent a lot of effort to help and I'm quite disappointed that you actually marked the other answer as "accepted", but not mine :( I don't think that's fair.

Answer (score 1):

I spent 2 days to solve the issue, I have `inlineRequires: false,` in metro config and changing it breaks the app.

I installed `yarn add react-native-get-random-values`.

Then imported `react-native-get-random-values` before `crypto-js` but it didn't work.

After hours of debugging, I found it's Babel's compiling order issue. `crypto-js` is always compiled earlier than `react-native-get-random-values`. In another word `crypto-js` looks for `global.crypto` before `react-native-get-random-values` assigns it. `import`s compile with higher priority than the rest of codes.

My file was:

```
import 'react-native-get-random-values'
import crypto from 'crypto-js`
```

The fix was lowering the compile order of `crypto-js` to make sure it compiles after `global.crypto` is assigned:

```
import 'react-native-get-random-values'
const crypto = require('crypto-js')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use : `npm install --save react-native-webview`

It's works for me.

Answer (score 0):

They fixed it in the webview tag 9.2.2, as shown in the changelog
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/releases/tag/v9.2.2